# Find and tag a number between a range

Tags: r

I have two dfs as below

```
>codes1

Country       State                       City  Start No    End No
IN          Telangana                Hyderabad    100        200
IN        Maharashtra       Pune (Bund Garden)    300        400
IN            Haryana                  Gurgaon    500        600
IN        Maharashtra                     Pune    700        800
IN            Gujarat    Ahmedabad (Vastrapur)    900        1000
```

Now i want to tag ip address from table 1

```
>codes2

ID     No
1      157
2      346
3      389
4      453
5      562
6      9874
7      98745
```

Now i want to tag numbers in `codes2` df as per the range given in `codes1` df for No column , expected ouput is

```
ID     No    Country     State          City
1     157       IN      Telangana     Hyderabad
2     346       IN     Maharashtra   Pune(Bund Garden)
.
.
.
```

Basically want to tag `No` column in `codes 2` with `codes1` according to the range (`Start No` and `End No`) that `No` observations falls in.

Also the order could be anything in `codes 2` df .

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Is the table `codes1` only this size or is it bigger ? You could do an `if` statement regarding that to associate every elements of `codes2`

Comment: @PierreChevallier The size for both table is bigger than shown here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're comfortable writing SQL, you might consider using the sqldf package to do something like

```
library('sqldf')
result <- sqldf('select * from codes2 left join codes1 on codes2.No between codes1.StartNo and codes1.EndNo')
```

you may have to remove special characters and spaces from the columnnames of your dataframes beforehand.

Comment: One thing though , this should return same number of rows as codes2 , i think there is a problem with that .

Comment: right, in that case we should do a left join instead of an inner join. (Just replace 'join' with 'left join' in the snippet).

Answer (score 6):

You could use the non-equi join capability of the `data.table` package for that:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(codes1)
setDT(codes2)

codes2[codes1, on = .(No > StartNo, No < EndNo),          ## (1)
       `:=`(cntry = Country, state = State, city = City)] ## (2)
```

(1) obtains matching row indices in `codes2` corresponding to each row in `codes1`, while matching on the condition provided to the `on` argument.

(2) *updates* `codes2` values for those matching rows for the columns specified directly *by reference* (i.e., you don't have to assign the result back to another variable).

This gives:

```
codes2
#    ID    No  cntry       state               city
# 1:  1   157     IN   Telangana          Hyderabad
# 2:  2   346     IN Maharashtra Pune (Bund Garden)
# 3:  3   389     IN Maharashtra Pune (Bund Garden)
# 4:  4   453     NA          NA                 NA
# 5:  5   562     IN     Haryana            Gurgaon
# 6:  6  9874     NA          NA                 NA
# 7:  7 98745     NA          NA                 NA
```